# .fbx and .blend have flipped normals in unity

Tags: export

Cannot export from blender to unity. On first image you can see imported .fbx and .obj(.obj works good).
Scale in blender is positive and normals facing outside.
I tried export .fbx with flipped normals from blender, but with flipped normals lightning in unity works wrong. 
[image: first exported as .fbx and .blend and the second(front) as .obj][image: looks working in blender with positive scale[![][2]][image: normals are outside]

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63642/after-import-to-unity-all-my-normals-are-flipped

Comment: I finally found it!

Comment: It looks like .obj and meshes is totally ok, but while importing with my armature it goes wrong. So i checked my armature and scale by X axis was -1, and right after importing good looking .obj was affected by negative scaled armature and normals gone wild. In blender, i applied scale to armature by selecting armature and pressing Ctrl+A a then Scale, same as people said in other threads about messing .obj
Shame on me, i need to be more careful

Answer (score 1):

It looks like .obj and meshes is totally ok, but while importing with my armature it goes wrong. So i checked my armature and scale by X axis was -1, and right after importing good looking .obj was affected by negative scaled armature and normals gone wild. In blender, i applied scale to armature by selecting armature and pressing Ctrl+A a then Scale, same as people said in other threads about messing .obj Shame on me, i need to be more careful