# Some Polygons disappear, when import to Unity trough FBX

Tags: export, unity, .fbx

Today i was working on a lightsaber for my unity project, but after i was nearly finished I saw, that there were some polygons not visible in Unity. I searched for that problem and found, that the reason could be that those polygons were N-Polygons, but after cutting the two polygons into tris, it still wouldn't show up.
While writing this i also found out, that my materials are not being exported correctly, that all worked half a hour ago.

octagon -> cut into tris (the flat thing is a bone)

[image: octagon -> cut into tris]

octagon missing (on top too, not only on sides)

[image: octagon missing]

materials in blender project

[image: materials in blender project]

materials in blender trough FBX ex- and import

[image: materials in blender trough FBX ex- and import]

how it should look like in the end in unity

[image: how it should look like in the end in unity]

how it should look expanded

[image: how it should look expanded]

EDIT: all disappearing polygons would be inside the object, if it had no pose, maybe that's why they are not visible in Unity, but there has to be a fix for that somehow.

EDIT2: importing through .blend to Unity does not take the materials or those missing polygons

Comment: The normals of the ngons are not facing outwards: you'll have flip them or make a double sided material in Unity.

Comment: Maybe this one is a better question to reference: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19325/why-is-my-mesh-inversed-when-imported-to-unity

Comment: thanks, how do i mark this question as "solved", etc.?

For others: There seems to be no way to import those materials to unity, so you have to make them in unity; Unity materials are not that difficult

Comment: There is no need, the question is marked as "duplicate", that means it has its solution in another thread (see the top of the page, before the links to other answers)